# Unrecognized selector - save to Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Help please to solve the problem - I do not understand why there is an error - unrecognized selector send to instance.

The error occurs when this code in AppDelegate is executed:

```
TMMonth *m = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TMMonth" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
m.paymentMonth=@"month";
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

reason: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TMMonth name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f993bdbbb00'

But in my code there is no selector 'name' in TMMonth class.

https://github.com/maks-84/paymentApp.git

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question.  There are many reasons not to point to a repository hosted elsewhere, and the simplest is that no one is going to go through it to find your problem.

Comment: i understand and wait for good people:)))

Answer (score 0):

error occurs  when execute code in AppDelegate

```
TMMonth *m = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TMMonth" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
m.paymentMonth=@"month";
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

---

```
reason: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TMMonth name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f993bdbbb00'
```

But in my code no selector 'name' in TMMonth class